How to access whatsapp web without qr-code with Rselenium firefox?
I am using Windows 7, I have both chrome webdriver version 108.0.5359.71 and geckodriver with version 0.34.0, and also installed mozilla firefox browser with version 115
With chrome, I actually can surf the whatsapp web (automatically bypass the qr-code), with these settings:
user_agent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.5359.71 Safari/537.36"
language <- "en-US,en;q=0.5"
accept_language <- "en-US,en;q=0.9"
platform <- "Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64"
chrome_user_data_dir <- "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
firefox_user_data_dir <- "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles"

options <- list(
      chromeOptions = list(
        args = c(
          paste0("--user-agent=", user_info$user_agent),
          paste0("--lang=", user_info$language),
          paste0("--user-data-dir=",chrome_user_data_dir)
        )
      )
    )

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port = 4567L, chromever = NULL, verbose=F, 
               extraCapabilities = options)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

However I need to access the whatsapp web using firefox since the chrome browser has known issues of videos playback for whatsapp web. These are my current settings for the firefox RSelenium setup:
firefox_profile_template <- list(
    browserName = "firefox",
    "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
      prefs = list("intl.accept_languages" = language),
      args = list(paste0("--user-agent=", user_agent), paste0("--user-data-dir=", user_data_dir))
    )
  )
)
    
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port = 4567L, chromever = NULL, verbose=F, 
               extraCapabilities = firefox_profile_template)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

And unfortunately these settings still make it stuck at whatsapp qr-code everytime the code run. And I actually do not have any idea either why the chrome works.
Note before navigate to web.whatsapp.com:
The first time I open my firefox browser is like this:

While the RSelenium firefox launch, is like this:

Anyone has experience on this please share your opinion! Thank you for your time!
